# Persist values for a known set of keys in Python

Tags: python, serialization

Use case: I sometimes write programs that want to store a little state between runs, e.g., "What was the last file selected last time this program ran?" I wanted a convenient way to track this state. Python's built-in `shelve` module is pretty good but I wanted a way to restrict the possible set of keys in the shelf so that I wouldn't (due to a bag) store something under some unexpected key that would never be read. While I was at it I made it so the you access values using `foo.a` instead of `foo['a']`, though I paid a price for this.

Questions I have about this code are:

1. Is there an easier way I could have accomplished this using built-in stuff or widely used libraries?
2. Did I choose the right design?

   1. I could have tried to inherit from one of the existing shelf classes, though the `shelve` module decides at runtime what sort of shelf you should get back from `shelve.open`.
   2. I could have tried to use descriptors to create my own pseudo-properties, sort of like what's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409112/implementing-python-persistent-properties), but I don't see a need to decide which fields to include at the class, rather than instance, level
3. Is there any less gross for me to use `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` (without having to store a list of fields to be handled as special)?
4. Did I handle the nested context managers (shelf within `RestrictedShelf`) correctly? Do I need a bunch of try/except logic in `__exit__`, as in the fourth example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24637294/2829764)?
5. Should I be defining my own exception classes, identical with `Exception` beyond the class name, as I did?
6. Is making _check_special_keys a class method, rather than a static method, the correct approach?

```
import shelve
import os
import sys

class UnexpectedKeyError(Exception):
    pass
class BadSpecialKey(Exception):
    pass

class RestrictedShelf(object):
    _SPECIAL_KEYS = ["_filepath", "_keys", "_shelf"]

    @classmethod
    def _check_special_keys(cls):
        for key in cls._SPECIAL_KEYS:
            if not key.startswith("_"):
                raise BadSpecialKey("Special key does not start with underscore: '{}'".format(key))

    def __init__(self, filepath, keys):
        self._filepath = filepath
        self._keys = list(keys) # Make a copy in case someone modifies the original list

        for key in keys:
            if not isinstance(key, str):
                raise TypeError("String object expected for key, {} found".format(key.__class__.__name__))
            # The keys in _SPECIAL_KEYS can't be used, but let's just rule out all keys that start with underscore for good measure
            if key.startswith("_"):
                raise ValueError("Key illegally starts with underscore: '{}'".format(key))

    def __enter__(self):
        self._shelf = shelve.open(self._filepath)
        for key in self._shelf.keys():
            if key not in self._keys:
                # This is not quite the same thing as a regular KeyError
                raise UnexpectedKeyError(key, "Shelf at '{}' contains unexpected key '{}'".format(self._filepath, key))
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if sys.version_info[0] <= 2:
            self._shelf.close()
        else:
            self._shelf.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        self.check_key(key)
        return self._shelf.get(key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in self._SPECIAL_KEYS:
            # https://stackoverflow.com/a/7042247/2829764
            super(RestrictedShelf, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        else:
            self.check_key(key)
            self._shelf[key] = value

    def check_key(self, key):
        if key not in self._keys:
            raise KeyError(key)

RestrictedShelf._check_special_keys()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with RestrictedShelf(os.path.expanduser("~/tmp/test.shelf"), "a b c".split()) as rs:
        print(rs.a) # `None` the first time you run this; `10` thereafter
        rs.a = 10
        print(rs.a) # 10
        print(rs.b) # None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Separation of concerns

There are three main features in this code:

1. Restricting the keys that can be stored in a dictionary.
2. Presenting a dictionary as a namespace.
3. Adding context manager behaviour to shelves in older versions of Python.

The principle of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) indicates that these should be implemented separately. See §3 below for one way to do this. This makes the code more understandable, testable, and reuseable.

#### 2. Other review points

1. There are no docstrings. What does this code do? How do I use it?
2. The code in `__exit__` assumes that [`Shelf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve.Shelf) objects have context manager behaviour in Python 3.0 or later. But the documentation says that this behaviour was only added in Python 3.4.
3. Storing `_keys` as a list means that checking to see if a key is valid takes time proportional to the number of keys. It would be better to store the keys in a set so that checking validity takes constant time.
4. There are implementations of `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` but not `__delattr__`.
5. A caller who tried to store a key `check_key` in the shelve would end up overwriting the method of that name.

#### 3. Revised code

1. Restricting the keys that can be stored in a dictionary.

   ```
   import collections.abc

   class RestrictedMapping(collections.abc.MutableMapping):
       """A proxy for a mapping that restricts the set of allowable keys.

       >>> d = RestrictedMapping({0:0, 1:1}, range(3))
       >>> del d[1]
       >>> d[2] = 2
       >>> d[3] = 3
       Traceback (most recent call last):
           ...
       KeyError: 3
       >>> sorted(d.items())
       [(0, 0), (2, 2)]

       """
       def __init__(self, mapping, keys):
           keys = set(keys)
           for key in mapping:
               if key not in keys:
                   raise ValueError('invalid key {}'.format(key))
           self.keys = keys
           self.mapping = mapping
           super(RestrictedMapping, self).__init__()

       def _check_key(self, key):
           if key not in self.keys:
               raise KeyError(key)

       def __getitem__(self, key):
           self._check_key(key)
           return self.mapping[key]

       def __setitem__(self, key, value):
           self._check_key(key)
           self.mapping[key] = value

       def __delitem__(self, key):
           self._check_key(key)
           del self.mapping[key]

       def __iter__(self):
           return iter(self.mapping)

       def __len__(self):
           return len(self.mapping)
   ```
2. Presenting a dictionary as a namespace.

   ```
   class Namespace(object):
       """A proxy for a mapping that provides access to items via attribute
       lookup.

       >>> d = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
       >>> n = Namespace(d)        # n is now a proxy for d
       >>> n.d = 4
       >>> n.a, n.b, n.c, n.d
       (1, 2, 3, 4)
       >>> del n.b
       >>> sorted(d.items())
       [('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]

       """
       def __init__(self, mapping):
           super(Namespace, self).__setattr__('_mapping', mapping)

       def __getattr__(self, attr):
           return self._mapping[attr]

       def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
           self._mapping[attr] = value

       def __delattr__(self, attr):
           del self._mapping[attr]
   ```
3. Combining restriction on keys, presentation as namespace, and addition of context manager behaviour.

   ```
   from contextlib import contextmanager
   import shelve

   @contextmanager
   def restricted_shelve(filename, keys):
       shelf = shelve.open(filename)
       try:
           yield Namespace(RestrictedMapping(shelf, keys))
       finally:
           shelf.close()
   ```

#### 4. Namespace antipattern

Presenting a mapping as a namespace instead of a dictionary is superficially attractive because `n.name` is three characters shorter than `d['name']`, but it's an antipattern in Python. (The only place this pattern is used in the standard library is in the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module.)

The problems are:

1. Attribute names need to be syntactically valid as Python identifiers, so you have to be very sure you're never going to need an attribute called `class` or `return` or `1` or whatever.
2. There will be collisions between the data attributes and the implementation attributes. In my version in §3.2 above you can't have attributes named `_mapping` or `__init__` or `__dict__` or `__slots__` or ...
3. There's no easy way to get at the list of attributes.
4. There's not much you can do with a namespace-like object: the Python standard library usually expects you to use mappings instead. For example, you can't pass a namespace to [`itertools.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap), or convert it to JSON using [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps), or output it as CSV using [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), and so on.

#### 5. Answers to questions

1. As far as I know, there's no easy way to implement features 1 (restriction on keys) and 2 (presentation as namespace). Feature 3 (adding context manager behaviour) is more easily done using [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) as shown in §3.3 above.
2. Your design puts all features into one class. This technique is known as the "[big ball of mud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud)".
3. Since your code knows exactly when it is assigning a special attribute, it can call `super().__setattr__` itself, thus avoiding the need for special handling in the `__setattr__` method. See §3.2 above.
4. Your code looks OK to me, but writing [`__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__exit__) methods is complicated and so (if you can) it's better to use [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) which takes care of this complexity for you.
5. It's sensible to define your own exception classes, but it's good practice to inherit directly from [`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception) only if there is no close match in the exception hierarchy. Here `UnexpectedKeyError` is a runtime problem caused by an invalid value of the correct type, so it makes sense to inherit from [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError).

   The `BadSpecialKey` exception indicates a static programming error, not runtime exceptional behaviour, so I would use an assertion here.
6. It would be better to avoid having special keys altogther: you'll see in §3 above that I didn't need them. But if you must, then `@classmethod` makes slightly more sense: in theory you might have a subclass with a different value for `_SPECIAL_KEYS`.

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot to learn here. I see what you mean about the namespace antipattern and will avoid it in the future. However, let me add that `namedtuple` does function as a namespace. I think that may have been my inspiration; you could describe what I'm trying the accomplish with the code above as either a restricted shelf (as I did) or as a persistent mutable namedtuple.

Comment: Good point about `namedtuple`. It looks as if the [recordtype](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/recordtype/) package provides a mutable record type, but I don't know whether it serializes easily.